# Javascript: cross-browser serverless file upload and download

Tags: javascript, file, api, cross-browser

So I'm working on a web app where a user will need to:

- provide a file full of data to work on
- save their results to a file

All the manipulation is done in javascript, so I don't really have a need for server-side code yet (just static hosting), and I like it that way.

In Firefox, I can use their [file manipulation api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications) to allow a user to upload a file directly into the client-side code (using a standard `<input type=file/>`) and create an object URL out of a file so a user can save a file created by the client-side code.

```
<input type="file" id="input" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
<a download="doubled" id="ex">right-click and save as</a>
<script>
  function handleFiles(fileList){
    var builder = new MozBlobBuilder();
    var file = fileList[0];
    var text = file.getAsBinary();
    builder.append(text);
    builder.append(text);
    document.getElementById('ex').href = window.URL.createObjectURL( builder.getBlob() );
  }
</script>
```

So this is great.  Now I want to do the same in other browsers - or, at least, modern versions of other browsers.  Do similar APIs exist for Chrome and IE?  If so, has anyone already built a cross-browser wrapper that I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mostly available on Firefox 3.6+, Chrome 10+, Opera 11.1+, and hopefully Safari 6 and IE 10.

See: http://caniuse.com/#search=FileReader.

Comment: Yay! That's a really nifty tool.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [FileSaver.js](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side) and the [a[download] attribute](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download) (supported in Chrome dev channel). Blob (object) URLs have somewhat [limited support](http://caniuse.com/#search=blob%20url) right now.

Comment: awesome - I had just figured out that I needed something like blob urls to save stuff I had generated.