# Client side (javascript) file upload encryption

Tags: javascript, encryption, file-upload

I'm trying to build a method for encrypting a file client side and upload it. The goal is to store the file encrypted on the server and only the end-user should be able to decrypt the file. This question has sort of been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921832/client-side-javascript-jquery-file-manipulation-before-after-upload-download), but I think I made some more progress.

My plan is to use the new Javascript File API to manipulate the file and upload it. Encryption could be done with the [Stanford Javascript Crypto Library](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/). The file should be read in chunks so it isn't completely read into memory. Every chunk is then encrypted by the crypt library. I can't figure out how to implement this. As a start I have this:

```
var fd = new FormData();
var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
fd.append("file", file);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/upload/");
xhr.send(fd);
```

Which is just a regular javascript upload. I'm trying to build a Crypt object that mimics the behavior of a File object and pass this to FormData. For every data chunk read by formdata the object should read a chunk from the file and encrypt this. I just can't figure out how FormData is processing a File object and if it possible to replicate this behavior. I'm not sure if it is the right way to do it, anybody has a suggestion?

**UPDATE:** Ok I'm much further now. I'm using file.slice to read the file in chunks. Then every chunk is encrypted and transformed back into a blob using a the BlobBuilder. This blob is then put into a FormData object and submitted to the server. The server will concatenate these blobs. Encrypting and decrypting one chunk with the browser is working. Now I'm working on download and decrypting multiple chunks.

There are still some problems to solve:

- The name of the file is lost, it is not yet possible to set a FileName for a file object.
- The encryption is still blocking (no ui update), but I think I can solve this with webworkers.
- I can't predict the chunk size while downloading. The unencrypted chunk size is known, but for encrypted data this seems to differ. This encrypted data is stored in JSON form, I prefer not to do a string search for }. And I prefer not to store this server side.
- Although I'm reading the file chunked, Firefox seemt to have a memory leak or read the complete file into memory. This becomes a problem for multi gigabyte files.

Comment: Who are you trying to protect it from? Why don't you just use https?

Comment: @Spudley that depends of course, if you want to encrypt the file on the client side as to make sure that the server side has no access to the original content than a solution like this is required. HTTPS would only prevent a man in the middle getting access.

Comment: @Spudley: exactly, this way the file is protected from everybody, even the server maintainer or hacker.

Comment: If someone hacks the server, they can modify the JS code to harvest keys. Also, if you don't use HTTPS, then a middleman could also do this.  Encryption does, however, make it somewhat harder for someone who hacks the server to decrypt files uploaded before the hack took place; but in that case, it makes no difference whether the encryption was done at the client or at the server.

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen: What you say is correct, but this is not a question about if it is a good idea or not or what could happen. It is a question about how to do it with javascript. Encrypting a file client side is more secure than not doing it. And of course we will use https. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure?  That is, can you think of an attack scenario where the attacker would succeed if the encryption was done in JS at the client, but not if it was done at the server?  And, if yes, what does the scenario presume about the attacker's abilities?

Comment: The data should be stored encrypted. We don't want to send unencrypted data or keys over the wire. Yes, we will use HTTPS. But letting the encryption happen server side implies the server needs the key. The server should never have access to the key. Storage of the data may be done by a 3rd party or somewhere 'in the cloud' eventually. We want the encryption to happen as close to the user as possible.

Comment: Ok i'm making more progress. I think I should use the [BlobBuilder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/BlobBuilder) to construct a encrypted file object. I can iterate over the file/blob, encrypt each chunk and append it to the blobbuilder. This Blobbuilder I can give to the FormData object. The only problem is that this will read the complete file into memory. This can bad when the file is big (600MB) since probably it is in memory encrypted and unencrypted.

Comment: Memory is probably going to be one of the  big issues here - not sure whether browser-based JavaScript is up to the task. Have you considered using Java, Flash or bulding a completely custom uploading program?  (I don't know what Flash's encryption capabilities are though)

Comment: .. or use a local encryption method like TrueCrypt and upload the encrypted container? Don't know whether that is feasible in your situation, just thinking of alternatives

Comment: We prefer to have a cross platform browser only and easy to use solution. Using javascript might be slow, but it does the job. Maybe we will work on acceleration of the encryption algorithm using nacl for google chrome, if it ever will be enabled by default.

Comment: If you are curious here is the [upload](http://code.google.com/p/filebender/source/browse/trunk/filebender/static/js/upload.js) and [download](http://code.google.com/p/filebender/source/browse/trunk/filebender/static/js/download.js) javascript code. Note that this is a proof-of-concept prototype.

Comment: Actually, this is completely wrong to think that because the encryption is done at server side the server needs the key! You can store the key in the session when the user logs in and the server has no key stored... See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Following is a solution that strongly protects files.

Pro:

- An attacker can access the server but won't be able to use the data.
- Even you (the developer) cannot access the data.

Cons:

- If user loses its password, data is lost too.
- Even you (the developer) cannot access the data (This means you cannot help the user if he encounters any problems).

If its what you need, go for it ^^. Note: all that follows happens on the Server side.

1. use https for all transmissions
2. When the user log in, create a hash of the user's password (e.g. sha(password + salt))
3. Store the hash in the user's session
4. When an upload is done, use symmetric encryption (e.g. AES) to encipher the data with the hash stored in the session as the key.
5. When a download is done, use the same symmetric decryption method to decipher the file and send it back to the user.

This means that only a logged user can access the data as plain. And only the user to whom the data belongs. The only possibility to access the user's data is to know his password.

Note: if the user that uploads the file and the one that read the file are not the same person, you can use a combination of asymmetric and symmetric encryption instead:

1. generate a public/private key pair for the recipient.
2. (symmetric) encrypt the private key with the recipient's hash or a
   dependency of
       his password.
3. <strike>When a file is uploaded, asymmetric encipher with the recipient's
   public key.</strike>
4. (new) Asymmetric encryption appear to be much slower than symmetric encryption (10-100x depending on algorithms/architecture). Hence it is far better to generate a random number (the session key), asymmetric-encrypt twice (once with sender's public key, once with recipient's public key) it and store them. Then use symmetric encryption to encrypt the file (use the plain session key as the symmetric key).
5. When the recipient wants to access the file:

   a) decipher his private key with his hash or password dependency.

   b) <strike>asymmetric decipher the file with the private key.</strike>

   b) (new) Use private key to decipher the recipient's encrypted session key. Then use symmetric decryption to decipher the file.

Hope this helps.