# Read and Write to a file using html: client side

Tags: html

Is it possible to read and write to a file at client side using HTML? I am not planning to use any of server side programming for this. Is it achievable?

Comment: You need to add more details. Are you planning to save html file itself? Is there any text block you are going to save as a file? Do you want to perform file manipulations on client side from browser? What all are the things you have already tried?

Comment: I am trying to create, manipulate and read the file. I need to understand if it is feasible before progressing.

Comment: Seems like your question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921832. Please have a look once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Client side (javascript/jQuery) file manipulation before/after upload/download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921832/client-side-javascript-jquery-file-manipulation-before-after-upload-download)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to write data and save it per user you can use browsers local storage  or cookies api's, if you want to write data which will serve all the users in the app you to use a server which will manage the writings of the file, because the file must sit at the server, and the client cannot write directly into a file in the server.

Here's a brief review about local storage if you decide you want to use it -  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp